# SSH key rejected by google compute engine instance

Tags: ssh, ftp, ssh-keys, google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

I generated my ssh key through the google sdk shell, then i went to put my key in FileZilla and connect to my google compute engine instance and it wont accept my key.  How do i fix this?

Comment: What is your operating system ?

Comment: @DeadEye debian i believe

Comment: Ok. What do you mean by "It won't accept my key" ?

Comment: @DeadEye it says "Error: Disconnected: No supported authentication methods available (server sent: publickey)" and then on the next line it says "Error: Could not connect to server"

Answer (score 1):

It seems like your ssh key is not loaded by Filezilla.
You can try two different solutions :

1/ Connect to the GCE through a SSH connection in your shell, then try to connect with FileZilla (this uses the SSH_AUTH_SOCK environment variable)

2/ Add your key to FileZilla :

- Click on "Edit" and then "Settings"
- Go to "Connection" and then "SFTP"
- Click on "Add keyfile"
- Select your private key file and open it.
- Click on OK

Use sftp://INSTANCE and your username to connect to your GCE instance.

Answer (score 0):

Please check, if you are connecting using the correct user name. Google sometimes has problems parsing the username out of the pasted public key.

You can check the username associated to the key on https://console.developers.google.com/project/$yourprojectid/compute/metadata/sshKeys

Comment: That was my first issue, but i got past that and ran into this error

Comment: it says "Error: Disconnected: No supported authentication methods available (server sent: publickey)" and then on the next line it says "Error: Could not connect to server"